# SL 4: TextBox doesn't get Ctrl-V?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, textbox, keydown

We have a TextBox control as part of a larger UserControl.
The UserControl has an MVVMLight RelayCommand bound to the KeyDown event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger> </i:Interaction.Trigger>
```

When the TextBox has focus, the KeyDown events for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key are seen, but not the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
I added a handler for the KeyDown for the TextBox in code-behind:

```
                     KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"

        private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("textBox_KeyDown Key: {0}  Modifier: {1}", e.Key, Keyboard.Modifiers));
        e.Handled = false;
    }
```

Similar result -- a KeyDown event for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is handled, but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't show up.
The message bubbles up through other handlers, but is never marked handled.
Any ideas on why the TextBox isn't getting the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?
Thanks for any insights.

**Update:**  Oh, for Pete's sake...  I added a KeyUp handler in the code-behind, and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> appears there.  However, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> appears in a KeyDown handler when a different control (a containing ScrollViewer, for example) is the source of the KeyDown.
**Update the Second:**  With a new, sparse project, I verified that the TextBox.KeyDown handler does NOT get called for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, while TextBox.KeyUp gets called for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  Is it possible to "pass along" the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> event to another TextBox?